# How to merge php and html code?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I want to show a table. I am getting rows from database and according to that I want to show the data in table data.

I want to show an image which will have source from database.

As I am using ajax I am calling getPosts from ajax and showing it in a table, so I am returning the data from getPosts.php to show in a table.

I have attempted to do it but getting stuck in syntax.  I want to add conditions while displaying data in table data.

So It is giving an error.

getPosts.php

```
    <?php 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

include 'Database.php';

$database = new Database(Constants::DBHOST,Constants::DBUSER,Constants::DBPASS,Constants::DBNAME);

$dbConnection = $database->getDB();

$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$posts='';

if (count($results > 0)) {

    $posts.='<table><tr><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Url</th></tr>';

    foreach($results as $row) {

        $posts .= '<tr><td>' . $row['title'] . '</td> <td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>'  // getting error here 

              if (strcmp($row['url_type'],"2"))
                  {
                      '<td><a href="'.$row['ur'].'" target="_blank">
    <image src="'.$row['thumb_url'].'" height="200" width="200"></image>
    </a></td>';
                  }

                  else{

        '<td>' . $row['url'] . '</td></tr>';

    }
    }

} else {

    $posts.='<tr><td>No data found</td></tr>';

}

$posts.='</table>';

echo $posts;

?>
```

html:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        td {
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Posts</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>


        $(document).ready(function() {


            getValue();

        });
        function getValue() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'getPosts.php',
                dataType: 'text',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {

                    // alert(result);

                    $('#table').html(result);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table id="table" style="width:60%">

    </table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Or Can I show these post in different format or design? I want to show the description,likes,views of post a thumbnail and url.

Maybe like this:

```
<div id="post">

<p>Description</p>
<a href="https://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/209597030" target="_blank">
<image src="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/lQMdhS_oOvA/default.jpg" height="200" width="200"></image>
</a>
<p>likes</p><p>views</p>
<p>url</p>
```

I want to make it presentable.

Comment: `So It is giving an error` what error(s) ?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\AgTv\getPosts.php on line 33
 syntax error. @OldPadawan

Comment: You can open a PHP file as your HTML and use _Session to access data in between. I find that much easier than doing POST/GET with Ajax

Comment: you need to close the line, then concatenate again in if/else statement

Comment: If I closed the statement then I can only see the description and title.@OldPadawan

Comment: I did *not* say `close statement` I said `close the line` (with ;)

Comment: @Sid : please check what I mean, my answer at the bottom of the page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to close the line, then proceed the if/else statement and concatenate in it :

```
<?php

$posts .= '<tr><td>'.$row['title'].'</td> <td>'.$row['description'].'</td>';  /* close here*/

     if (strcmp($row['url_type'],"2"))
         {
         $posts .= '<td><a href="'.$row['ur'].'" target="_blank">
<image src="'.$row['thumb_url'].'" height="200" width="200"></image></a></td>';
          }
          else
          {
         $posts .= '<td>' . $row['url'] . '</td></tr>';
          }

?>
```

Comment: hello are you there?

Comment: @Sid : any problem ?

Comment: yes I want to concatenate a link but its not working. <a href="videos/.'.$row['url'].'"  in this videos is not getting concatenate with url. @ OldPadawan

Comment: When you have a problem, declare $var first then use double quotes like ˋ$myvideo = "$row['url'];` then you don't need concatenation anymore : ˋecho"<a href='$myvideo'>video</>";`

Comment: Beware of one too many " on my previous comment, can't edit on phone! ˋ$myvideo = $row...`

Comment: I tried like this      $myvideo = $row['url'];
                  $url = "images/".$myvideo;  but not working. @OldPadawan

Comment: Nope ! Just ˋimages/$myvideo ˋ no need for extra quotes or concatenation

Comment: I am unable to get the path I need, when I did print $url I can see only the image name i.e $row['url'] and not images/$row['url'];

Comment: @Sid : you need a regular ˋlink` (HTML 'a') or an ˋimage ` (HTML <img src="" ...) ? I can't see what you exactly need... and please explain your folders tree

Answer (score 2):

I hope below code solved your problem :

```
<?php 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
include 'Database.php';

$database = new Database(Constants::DBHOST,Constants::DBUSER,Constants::DBPASS,Constants::DBNAME);

$dbConnection = $database->getDB();

$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts");
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$posts='';

if (count($results > 0)) {

    $posts.='<table><tr><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Url</th></tr>';
    foreach($results as $row) {
        $posts .= '<tr><td>' . $row['title'] . '</td> <td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>';  // <- You need to close your $posts variable here. 

              if (strcmp($row['url_type'],"2"))
              {
                 $posts .= '<td><a href="'.$row['ur'].'" target="_blank"><image src="'.$row['thumb_url'].'" height="200" width="200"></image></a></td></tr>'; // You need to store this result in your post variable like this.
              }

              else{

                $posts .= '<td>' . $row['url'] . '</td></tr>'; // You need to store this result in your $posts variable as well. Because both if and else are give an different output. So if you want to display output which return by if and else then you must have to store output in $posts variable.
            }
    }

} else {
    $posts.='<tr><td>No data found</td></tr>';

}
?>
```